# Putting future TA position on my CV

Tags: cv

I am writing my CV for an application for a graduate program. The application process starts in February and the graduate program begins in September.

I recently accepted a position as a teaching assistant at my current university, and my employment officially begins in April.

Is it acceptable/advisable that I put this fact in my CV, which I will send in before my teaching assistant job officially starts?

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you could list it with an appropriate comment, like "expected, Apr 2016 -" but I wouldn't say it's advisable.  It seems unlikely to me that any graduate program will accept you because you will have had some a little teaching experience by the time you start.  Presumably you were offered a TA position because some people in the department thought highly of you.  At least one of these people should be writing you a recommendation, and will mention it if they think it is important.  What's more important is their evidence/explanation of why they thought highly enough of you to offer you such a position in the first place.